# Ruby: If I wanted to convert order.price to a decimal value, do I use order.price.to_i?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very beginner's question: I noticed that there's no .to_d (such as order.price.to_d to convert order.price into a decimal). Say order.price is currently a string; can I then use order.price.to_i to convert it into a decimal?

Comment: Note, `to_d` has changed dramatically since this question was asked. It now does `nil.to_d => 0.0` and `"1.0".to_d => 0.1e1`. In my experience, it is almost always preferred to use `to_d` instead of `to_f`. But I'm glad to hear from anybody about when it is better to use `to_f` instead of `to_d`. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Ruby corelib documentation](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001509) is your friend!

```
>> "9.95".to_f
=> 9.95
>> "9.95".to_f.class
=> Float
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use BigDecimal instead of Float if you plan on doing any calculations with the price.  It retains the precision and isn't subject to the rounding errors that float is.